# How to insert " character in string variable?

Tags: vb.net, string, variables, special-characters

How to insert this?

```
Dim SpCharacter As String = " " "
```

or

```
Dim XMLSitemap As String = "<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">"
```

insert with all Content **"** and **>** and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it by doubling it:

```
Dim SpCharacter As String = " "" "

Dim XMLSitemap As String = "<urlset xmlns=""http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"">"
```

See [String Basics in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234766.aspx) on MSDN:

> Visual Basic interprets two quotation marks in a string literal as one quotation mark in the string.

Comment: @Qrosh - I have no idea what you mean. You have posted something in your question, which is what I followed. If you want a `"` to appear in the string, you need to put two of them, so Visual Basic will understand that it need to put one `"` there.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET you can escape `"` by passing it twice in a row:

```
Dim SpCharacter As String = " "" "
```

or

```
Dim XMLSitemap As String = "<urlset xmlns=""http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"">"
```

Comment: It will be `"`! It's just a way to tell compiler it's a part of a string, not a start/end of it!